# Find and replace just a part of a xml value using XQuery?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, dml

I have an XML in one of my columns, that is looking something like this:

```
<BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path3/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path21/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path15/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
</BenutzerEinstellungen>
```

I would like to replace **all** `test123` occurances (there can be more than one) in `VorlagenHistorie` with `another test`, that all paths direct to test123 after my update.

I know, how you can check and replace all values with an equality-operator, I saw it in this answer: 
[Dynamically replacing the value of a node in XML DML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435485/dynamically-replacing-the-value-of-a-node-in-xml-dml)

But is there a CONTAINS Operator and is it possible to replace INSIDE of a value, I mean only replace a part of the value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there always one `State` element and a list of  `VorlagenHistorie` elements and nothing else?

Comment: The State object is only an example, there a ton other elements in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not suggest a string based approach normally. But in this case it might be easiest to do something like this

```
declare @xml XML=
'<BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
</BenutzerEinstellungen>';

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@xml AS nvarchar(MAX)),'/test123/','/anothertest/') AS xml);
```

### UPDATE

If this approach is *to global* you might try something like this:

I read the XML as derived table and write it back as XML. In this case you can be sure, that only Nodes with `VorlageHistorie` will be touched...

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/BenutzerEinstellungen/State)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [State]
      ,(
        SELECT REPLACE(vh.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),'/test123/','/anothertest/') AS [*]
        FROM @xml.nodes('/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie') AS A(vh)
        FOR XML PATH('VorlagenHistorie'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('BenutzerEinstellungen');
```

### UPDATE 2

Try this. It will read all nodes, which are not called `VorlagenHistorie` *as is* and will then add the `VorlageHistorie` nodes with replaced values. The only draw back might be, that the order of your file will be different, if there are other nodes after the `VorlagenHistorie` elements. But this should not really touch the validity of your XML...

```
declare @xml XML=
'<BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <Unknown>Original</Unknown>
       <UnknownComplex>
       <A>Test</A>
       </UnknownComplex>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
</BenutzerEinstellungen>';

SELECT @xml.query('/BenutzerEinstellungen/*[local-name(.)!="VorlagenHistorie"]') AS [node()]
      ,(
        SELECT REPLACE(vh.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),'/test123/','/anothertest/') AS [*]
        FROM @xml.nodes('/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie') AS A(vh)
        FOR XML PATH('VorlagenHistorie'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('BenutzerEinstellungen');
```

### UPDATE 3

Use an updateable CTE to first get the values and then set them in one single go:

```
declare @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,xmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(
'<BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <Unknown>Original</Unknown>
       <UnknownComplex>
       <A>Test</A>
       </UnknownComplex>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
</BenutzerEinstellungen>')
,('<BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
    </BenutzerEinstellungen>');

WITH NewData AS
(
    SELECT ID
      ,xmlColumn AS OldData
      ,(
        SELECT t.xmlColumn.query('/BenutzerEinstellungen/*[local-name(.)!="VorlagenHistorie"]') AS [node()]
              ,(
                SELECT REPLACE(vh.value('.','nvarchar(max)'),'/test123/','/anothertest/') AS [*]
                FROM t.xmlColumn.nodes('/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie') AS A(vh)
                FOR XML PATH('VorlagenHistorie'),TYPE
               )
        FOR XML PATH('BenutzerEinstellungen'),TYPE
       ) AS NewXML
    FROM @tbl AS t
)
UPDATE NewData
SET OldData=NewXml;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: We have other elements, that could have the same string inside, but shouldnt be updated. Its very unlikely, but would be a risk.

Comment: @Jannik see my update... If there are more attributes you can just include them like I've done it with `State`

Comment: Well, we don't know them all, and they are pretty much dynamic unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. Can you tell me, how you execute that on a real table?

Comment: I have made a small mistake. Would it work with something like this? <BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <Unknown>Original</Unknown>
       <UnknownComplex>
       <A>Test</A>
       </UnknownComplex>
       <VorlagenHistorie>
   <innerElement>/path/path/test123/file.doc</innerElement>
    </VorlagenHistorie>
    <VorlagenHistorie>
   <innerElement>/path/path/test123/file123.doc</innerElement>
    </VorlagenHistorie>
    <VorlagenHistorie>
   <innerElement>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</innerElement>
    </VorlagenHistorie>
</BenutzerEinstellungen>

Comment: There is a problem with the pasted XML... the second and the third closing `</innerElement>` includes weird characters between the `n` and the `t`. There is 8204 and 8203 (unicode). However this got into your tag names, [this might be related[(http://stackoverflow.com/q/2973698/5089204). If you need further help: Please give details about *Would it work with something like this*. And please open a new question and place a link to this to avoid chameleon questions, Thx.

Comment: Btw: I just tested this with your XML from comment and wrote the first `innerElement` via copy'n'paste into the bad closing tags. Seems to work though...

Comment: It was just an example pseudo XML. Do you have a solution for that one aswell? I would need to replace the innerElement values and not the VorlagenHistorie-values. It seems like thats not as simple as changing a path in your Update3. Maybe you have an idea how to update your script. Your script worked perfectly in the other XML-structure. It would be the last thing, I asked regarding this Topic.

Comment: @Jannik, no problem, you can ask as much as you like, but please start a new question. This one gets overloaded. SO is - beside your hope to find a solution for your issue - a Q&A-collection for future visitors. Such questions will not help other people... So the principlce is KISS (Keep it small and simple, one issue, one question, one solution). So: Please start a new question with a link to this (add a comment with the link and `@Shnugo`. Paste example XML (reduced, but with all varieties) and will pop up there soon.

Comment: @Jannik, one question to help you to articulate the new question: Is this new structure with `innerElement` now the new *one-and-only* structure or do you have both (the former without `innerElement` and this? If there are `innerElements` are there other values *within* `VorlageHistorie` which should not be changed?

Answer (score 2):

If @shnugo's answer does not fit your needs, you can use XML/XQuery approach:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
    </BenutzerEinstellungen>';
DECLARE @from nvarchar(20) = N'test123';
DECLARE @to nvarchar(20) = N'another test';
DECLARE @newValue nvarchar(100) = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(100), @xml.query('(/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie/text()[contains(.,sql:variable("@from"))])[1]')), @from, @to)

SET @xml.modify('
    replace value of (/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie/text()[contains(.,sql:variable("@from"))])[1]
    with sql:variable("@newValue")')

SELECT @xml
```

Comment: I will try this Approach and give you some Feedback :)

Comment: And what if there is one more node like `<VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/test123/third.doc</VorlagenHistorie>`? Or `VorlagenHistorie` nodes content will switch there places?

Comment: There can be more than one. This won't work with more than one, right?

Comment: Pawel, you are using the first `VorlagenHistorie` to build up your `@newValue`. But there are more than one. You migh count the number of `VorlagenHistorie` nodes and use a loop to inject the node's index as `sql:variable`...

Answer (score 2):

A weird solution, but it worked well:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<BenutzerEinstellungen>
       <State>Original</State>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/test123/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
       <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path5/test123/third.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
</BenutzerEinstellungen>';

DECLARE @Counter int = 1,
        @newValue nvarchar(max),
        @old nvarchar(max) = N'test123',
        @new nvarchar(max) = N'anothertest';

WHILE @Counter <= @xml.value('fn:count(//*//*)','int')
BEGIN
    SET @newValue = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(100), @xml.query('((/*/*)[position()=sql:variable("@Counter")]/text())[1]')), @old, @new)
    SET @xml.modify('replace value of ((/*/*)[position()=sql:variable("@Counter")]/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newValue")');
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END

SELECT  @xml;
```

Output:

```
<BenutzerEinstellungen>
  <State>Original</State>
  <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/file.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
  <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path/anothertest/second.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
  <VorlagenHistorie>/path/path5/anothertest/third.doc</VorlagenHistorie>
</BenutzerEinstellungen>
```

Comment: Funny, this is the approach I just suggest below Pawel's answer :-)

Comment: HI gofr1, I used your answer to place one more answer, because I think your approach can be widely enhanced by using more specific XPath. I vote this up, as I've *stolen* your code, but you've *stolen* Pawel's code, so I hope this is OK for you :-)

Comment: Hi @Shnugo it is OK for sure :) Honestly, I didn't read recent comments beyond Pawel's answer, I just post this solution as is. I don't think it is good way for current OP situation, but it can help another fellow developers.

Comment: Hi gofr1, you did not missing anything! Your answer came in in the same second as I posted my comment. We just had the same idea...

Comment: @Shnugo it just happens, I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

gofr1's answer might be enhanced by using more specific XPath expressions:

```
DECLARE @Counter int = 1,
        @newValue nvarchar(max),
        @old nvarchar(max) = N'test123',
        @new nvarchar(max) = N'anothertest';

WHILE @Counter <= @xml.value('fn:count(/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie)','int')
BEGIN
    SET @newValue = REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(100), @xml.value('(/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie)[sql:variable("@Counter")][1]','nvarchar(max)')), @old, @new)
    SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/BenutzerEinstellungen/VorlagenHistorie[sql:variable("@Counter")]/text())[1] with sql:variable("@newValue")');
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END

SELECT  @xml;
```